# What is difference between 'textEmailAddress' and 'textWebEmailAddress'

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I noticed that among other attributes, that we can specify for `EditText` as an `inputType`, there are two, that look similar:

1. textEmailAddress
2. textWebEmailAddress

[Google doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) has explained very less about this.

We can understand that `textWebEmailAddress` is something related to HTML or `WebView`, but I would like to know what exactly, the difference between the two is.

Comment: Not sure about the exact difference. A bit more info here.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are some resources I've found regarding these two `inputType`s:

> ... For example, textEmailAddress is a text field where the user will enter something that is an e-mail address (foo@bar.com) so the key layout will have an '@' character in easy access...

This was found [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/search/label/Input%20methods).

And then:

> ...You can specify the type of keyboard you want for your EditText object with the android:inputType attribute. For example, if you want the user to input an email address, you should use the textEmailAddress input type...

This was found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#Keyboard).

And the only thing I can find on `textWebEmailAddress` is:

> Variation of TYPE_CLASS_TEXT: entering e-mail address inside of a web form. This was added in HONEYCOMB. An IME must target this API version or later to see this input type; if it doesn't, a request for this type will be seen as TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS when passed through EditorInfo.makeCompatible(int).

This was found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EMAIL_ADDRESS).

From what I've seen in these sections, there is very little difference in the results, the keyboards are the same, just specified differently for different locations of inputs; one in a web form, one for general-purpose.

Also the `textWebEmailAddress` is only effective for Honeycomb and newer platforms, while the regular is compatible for all.  Although both could be used in older versions, per the documentation, they would operationally be a regular `textEmailAddress` anyways.

Comment: So what is the correct one for URL address, like on a web browser? Is it `textUri` ?

Comment: I would imagine you would use the InputType being equal to TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI

Comment: Wait how do I set it in XML ? There is nothing with the word "variation" for `inputType` attribute of EditText